# Can anyone suggest the steps to do CI/CD of angularjs using jenkins?

Tags: angularjs, jenkins, npm, build, continuous-integration

I have sample application in angularjs, I want to do CI/CD of that application using jenkins. I have installed the npm  node and grunt in jenkins server and configured a freestyle job, where in I have mentioned npm install(shell command). How to build the war file for that application?

Comment: you need a war file for angular js application ??

Answer (score 1):

For jenkins configuration 
Apart from normal repo configuration
Add Execute Shell:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
echo Building Angular UI...
cd ui/angular
grunt release
```

In the above configuration we need to move to angular code and then execute **grunt release**. This will create angular build. Then we can copy that build(may be using ant scripts) to our server webapp.

```
grunt.registerTask('release', [
    'clean:temp',
    'copy:setup',
    'requirejs:build',
    'copy:build',
    'cssmin',
    'replace',
]);

grunt.registerTask('deploy', [
    'release',
    'compress:zip',
    'clean:build'
]);
```

Yes we can create a new task deploy which will release our code and then zip the release folder.

Comment: do we get build in the form of war file?

Comment: No war file is not a standard for angular builds

Comment: I want to build the war or zip and push it to artifactory

Comment: grunt release will give what file ?